# Parameter only unbound report

Tags: ms-access, report

Not sure how possible this is, but I would like to create a report that is strictly unbound. Each time the report is opened, the user needs to populate the parameter boxes which populate the report. Looking for the result to be a single page containing the parameter values entered.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the following in Access 2010 and it seemed to work:

I created a new blank report and specified the following SQL query as its `Record Source`:

```sql
PARAMETERS [Value1] Text ( 255 ), Value2 Text ( 255 ); 
SELECT [Value1], [Value2] FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM MSysObjects) AS Dual;
```

I dropped two Text Box controls on the form and bound them to [Value1] and [Value2] respectively. When I open the report I am prompted for [Value1], then for [Value2], and then the report appears with the values I typed in.